# Logging in to mint with C#

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, webrequest

I want to get a csv file from mint.com and manipulate it in C#.  I have to log in to do this.  I have followed the suggestions of another post on Stack Overflow and have come up with the following code.  Unfortunately, the result I get is not the intended CSV but instead an error page.  Any insight into what I am doing wrong or how I could do this another way?

```
    string cookieHeader = CookieHeaderFromMintLogin("myusername","mypassword");
    string csvURL = "https://wwws.mint.com/transactionDownload.event?queryNew=&offset=0&filterType=cash&comparableType=8";
    string csv = getResponseWithCookies(csvURL, cookieHeader);

    string CookieHeaderFromMintLogin(string username, string password)
    {

        string formUrl = "https://wwws.mint.com/loginJumper.event"; // NOTE: This is the URL the form POSTs to, not the URL of the form (you can find this in the "action" attribute of the HTML's form tag
        string formBuilId = HttpUtility.UrlEncode("form-NAjKdtCT8Z5SuyDHTsmRREioaCMXVEJZpt8-9oaSMEY");
        string formId = HttpUtility.UrlEncode("mint_auth_mint_com_login_form");
        username = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(username);
        password = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(password);
        string formParams = string.Format("username={0}&password={1}&form_build_id={2}&form_id={3}", username, password, formBuilId,formId);
        WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(formUrl);
        req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        req.Method = "POST";
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(formParams);
        req.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
        using (Stream os = req.GetRequestStream())
        {
            os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }
        WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();

        return resp.Headers["Set-cookie"];
    }

    string getResponseWithCookies(string getUrl, string cookieHeader)
    {
        string pageSource;
        WebRequest getRequest = WebRequest.Create(getUrl);
        getRequest.Headers.Add("Cookie", cookieHeader);
        WebResponse getResponse = getRequest.GetResponse();
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(getResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            pageSource = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }

        return pageSource;
    }
```

Comment: And the error says what?

Comment: @RonBeyer  The content of csv is a page from mint: <h1>Perhaps you took a wrong turn?</h1> <p>Sorry about this! Here are a few things you can try:</p> <ul> <li><a href="/login.event">Log in again</a></li> <li><a href="/overview.event">Go to your overview</a></li> </ul>

Comment: Did you resolve this, Josh? The error you were getting suggests that you weren't properly logged in.

Comment: I agree that I wasn't properly logged in.  I was looking for some insight into why the code I posted wasn't properly logging in.  In the end, I gave up and downloaded an API someone put together in Python.

Comment: Alright, I'm working on it in C# now, I've found that it's token based authentication and so I'm working on grabbing and reusing the token. I'll let you know if I figure this out.